# img/div that fills the screen on load?

Tags: css

I am trying to set a background image like http://bklynsoap.com/ and have content underneath it. The image doesn't need to scale to the page, but I want it to fill the initial browser screen. I tried looking through their source code to find how they were doing it but no luck. Can anyone steer me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Look into their JS file.

It sets the dimensions of the first (top) `<div>`, and fills it out with an image. A timer is set upon page load, and after 10 seconds the window is scrolled down to the next `<div>`.